# Display Gridview row in descending order based on the integer value of the label in the column on RowDataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Display Gridview row in descending order based on the integer value of the label in the column on RowDataBound. I am binding a data in my Gridview in a label 'lblTitle' which is working fine, I have another label which is 'lblMatchcount', now I am not retrieving the value of 'lblMatchcount' from database, but getting the value of it from the other event on RowDataBound. Here I am hiding those rows whose 'lblMatchcount' value is '0', and also I want to sort the rows accordingly high to low based on the values of the 'lblMatchcount' in the RowDataBound. Any experience will be appreciated.
Below is my design view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="UCGridView" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="FId" CellPadding="4"
                ForeColor="#333333" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table style="width: 90%; text-align: center; border: 0px solid red;">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("Id")) %>'> </asp:Label>

                                        Title :
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" Style="font-weight: bold;" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("DTitle")) %>'> </asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                        Match count :<asp:Label ID="lblMatchcount" runat="server" Text="" Visible="true"></asp:Label>

                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

            </asp:GridView>
```

Below is the code behind:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows) //loop each row
        {
            Label lblMatchcount = gvr.FindControl("lblMatchcount") as Label;

            int mcount;
            mcount = int.Parse(lblMatchcount.Text);
            if(mcount==0)
            {
                gvr.Visible = false;
            }
            // Sort here based on the mcount value

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do it in your SQL Query itself. Avoid writing extra code for it.

Comment: As @noobprogrammer says, sort the data before you bind it to the GridView.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Actually I don't have lblMatchcount  field (column) in the database. The value for lblMatchcount is being populated after the TextChanged event from the TextBox and then it is handled in the RowDataBound. I assume that if there is no criteria (Column or Value) in the database then I'll have nothing to write or pass in the query and to bind, I hope I am making sense, if not could you show me how do you intend to do that? Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Query as I suggested to sort the data in descending order. You can order them based on primary key that you set. In this case it should be Id set as `PRIMARY KEY`. So ordering would be based on `Id` field only.

Supposing your query looks like this:

```
select Id, Title from your TableName
```

you just need to add `ORDER BY` clause to order your data followed by ASC|DESC where ASC is Ascending and DESC is Descending.

So your complete query would become

```
select Id, Title 
from your Table 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

DESC will order descending your data based on Id.

How To use it?

In your back-end code, create a method and call your sql query. And then call this method(which contains your SQL Query) on your Page_Load event. So it should be something like this:

```
public void PopulateData(){
     string connectionName = "YourConnectionString Name here";
     string query = "select Id, Title from YourTableName Order By Id desc";

     using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionName)){
     using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connectionName)){

           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapater(cmd);
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           sda.Fill(dt); 
           GridView1.DataSource = dt; // this will bind your GridView 
           GridView1.DataBind();

             }

          }

      }
```

Now call this Method `PopulateData` on your PageLoad() event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(!PostBack){
    PopulateData();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. But my table structure is not in a fashion that you are trying to show. I have a label which is 'lblMatchcount' in the gridview, now I am not retrieving the value of 'lblMatchcount' from database, NOT RETREIVING FROM DATABASE. The value of lblMatchcount is coming from the TextChanged event. I have a search TextBox and when the user type in the text in the search box it counts the number of words that matches and it passes it to 'lblMatchcount'. Then here I wish to arrange the record in descending or ascending order according to the value in the 'lblMatchcount'.

Comment: It seems like I have to change the structure of my table now, because I don't see any solution to it. What I can do is I'll add a column in my table with a name called lblMatchcount, and in the Gridview when the lblMatchcount gets it values, then I'll update the lblMatchcount field in the table with the generated lblMatchcount values from the page then rebind the Gridview again. This is the only possible solution I could see now.